# Generate auto increment serial number in java eclipse

Tags: java

I designed one form in java where textfield is there.so I want to display serial numbers in this textfield...means current textfield value should be 1..then I'll fill up these form and submitted...when I'll come back textfield value should be 2...after submitting this form textfield value become 3 and so on...So how to make auto increment serial number and display in JTextfield..

Here I used java eclipse and sqlite database.
I tried following code...

```
textField = new JTextField();
try {
    String query = "Select max(`Enquiry No`) as max from enquiry ";
    PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement(query);
    ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();

    while (rs.next()) {
        int num = rs.getInt(1);
        int inc = num + 1;
        textField.setText(valueOf(inc));
    }
} catch (Exception f) {
    f.printStackTrace();
}
```

please give solution for it

Comment: what does 'but not work' exactly mean?

Comment: it not gives any error and output also...textfield remains blank

Comment: Have you tried to directly run the statement within your DB client?

Comment: if i understand you want to make change the value every insertion ?

Comment: max query works...but how design code in while loop ? @kamehl23

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea simple after the insertion you should to call your method, i suggest something like this :

Insert function, you should to call it when you submit, after submit you had to call the second method

```
insertion_function(){
   //insert into your database
   //call your method which get max and show you the result
   set_max_function();
}

set_max_function() {
    textField = new JTextField();
    try {
        String query = "Select max(`Enquiry No`) as max from enquiry ";
        PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement(query);
        ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();

        while (rs.next()) {
            int num = rs.getInt(1);
            int inc = num + 1;
            textField.setText(valueOf(inc));
        }
    } catch (Exception f) {
        f.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Hope you understand the idea.

Comment: sir //@insert into your database...i used insert query...but i already have submit button where all data will be inserted...so how to use it ?

Comment: insertion_function();
  {
   try
   {
                String Query="insert into enquiry (`Enquiry No`,`Client`,`User`,`Purchase`,`Sales`,`Quotation No`,) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)";
    PreparedStatement pst=conn.prepareStatement(Query);
       pst.setString(1, textField.getText());
    String value=client.getSelectedItem().toString();
    pst.setString(2, value);
        ....
        
    pst.execute();
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Data Saved");
       }
   catch(Exception a)
   {
    a.printStackTrace();
   }

Comment: try
          {
     String query="Select max(`Enquiry No`) as max from enquiry ";
     PreparedStatement pst=conn.prepareStatement(query);
              ResultSet rs=pst.executeQuery();
           
           while(rs.next())
          {
            textField.setText(rs.getString("max"));
          }
          }
           catch(Exception a)
        {
         a.printStackTrace();
        }
          
    
  
    set_max_function();
  }